# Error trying to connect to an mvc server on ms-azure from a windows phone 8 app using webapi

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I'm a little bit new to all of these technologies so I'll try to be as clear as I can.

I'm writing a windows phone app that sends data in string format to a server:

```
public class sendDataControl
{
    private string response = "";

    public void sendToServer(string FullSTR)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://pricequeryserver.azurewebsites.net/api/ReceiptDataService/?incomingdata=");

            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri,FullSTR);
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            ...
            ...    
        }
    }

void webClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
            responseXml=e.Error.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(responseXml);
            return;
    }
    else
    {
            responseXml = e.Result;
    }
}
```

}

The server is an MVC4, basic, with api controller I added, that needs to get the data sent from the mobile.

As a test I'm just getting back a string that I send:

```
public class ReceiptDataServiceController : ApiController
{
    private ReceiptContext db = new ReceiptContext();
    ...
    ...

    public string GetDataFromMobile(string IncomingData) 
    {
        return IncomingData;
    }   
}
```

While running the application I get an error via responseXml:
"The remote server returned an error: NotFound".

The server returns the right answer from all kinds of browsers, while on IIS and on the azure but not from the mobile emulator.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for [UploadStringAsync overload you are using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms144239%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you will notice that it sends data using `POST` method. While in your controller you have only implemented `GET`. And for your

You have to use other [overload of UploadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms144240%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which lets you specify the HTTP VERB to use. And you must specify `GET`. Your client code should be converted to:

```
webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri,"GET", FullSTR);
```

And the best solution for simple `GET` operations like your is to actually use [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
var fullUri = new Uri("http://pricequeryserver.azurewebsites.net/api/ReceiptDataService/?incomingdata=" + FullStr);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(fullUri);
```

Anyway, your question has nothing to do with Windows Azure, thus the removed tag.

Comment: Thanks, working great.
I added the azure tag because it didn't work on IIS.